# "Bitwise assignment" in C? Assigning a variable's bits to another

Tags: c, bit

Is it possible to do a bitwise assignment in C? (Assigning the bits of a variable to another, assuming for simplicity that the source and the target of assignment have the same number of bits.)

For example, assign the number `int` 1 (which has bits `0...01`) to a float variable, obtaining not the float number 1.0f but the number (assuming IEEE-754 representation and assuming a float is 4 bytes as the int) with bits:

`0 (sign) 0000'0000 (exponent) 0...01 (mantissa)`

which would be a subnormal number (cause the exponent bits are all 0's and the mantissa is not zero), hence representing the number

`+ 2^-126 2^-23` (assuming mantissa has 23 bits, then 0..(23 zeroes in total)..1 is 2^-23), that is `2^-149`, that is approx. `1.4 10^-45`.

**NOTE**: I'm in the process of learning. I am not trying to do this in a real-life scenario.

Comment: It's called `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Given two objects `a` and `b` that are known to be the same size, you can copy the bits of `b` into `a` with `memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union for that:

```
int source;
float target;

union Data {
    int i;
    float f;
} data;

source = 42;
data.i = source;
target = data.f; // target should now have the bitwise equivalent of 42.
```

Be mindful about the sizes of the union members. If they are not equal I think they are padded to the right, but to be sure check with the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the bits of other types via pointers (including `memcpy`, which takes them as arguments) or via unions. There is already another answer about the former, so I'll focus on the union approach.

Union members share the same memory, so you could use bit fields or integer types to access the individual bits, and then view the same bits by using a member of another type. However, note that both accessing the value of another type via a union and bit fields themselves are implementation defined, so this is inherently non-portable. In particular it is not specified how the bits end up being aligned in relation to other union members…

An example for the case of floats:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union float_bits {
    float value;
    struct {
        unsigned mantissa:23;
        unsigned exponent:8;
        unsigned sign:1;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned bits:32;
    };
};

static void print_float_bits(union float_bits f) {
    printf("(%c %02x %06x) (%08x) %f\n", f.sign ? '-' : '+', (unsigned) f.exponent, (unsigned) f.mantissa, (unsigned) f.bits, f.value);
}

int main(void) {
    union float_bits f;

    f.value = 1;
    print_float_bits(f);
    f.sign = 1;
    print_float_bits(f);

    // Largest normal number
    f.sign = 0; f.exponent = 0xFE; f.mantissa = 0x7FFFFF;
    print_float_bits(f);

    // Infinity
    f.exponent = 0xFF; f.mantissa = 0;
    print_float_bits(f);

    return 0;
}
```

On my x86-64 machine with 32-bit IEEE-754 floats, compiled with clang, outputs:

```
(+ 7f 000000) (3f800000) 1.000000
(- 7f 000000) (bf800000) -1.000000
(+ fe 7fffff) (7f7fffff) 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
(+ ff 000000) (7f800000) inf
```

**Disclaimer**: Very much implementation defined behaviour, non-portable and dangerous. Bitfields used for readability of the example. Other alternatives would be to put an array of `char` or some integer type like `uint32_t` in the union instead of bitfields, but it's still very much implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Very interesting, and very clean example! It's the first time I see the notation `: n_bits` after struct's fields. Has this feature always been there in C? Is it there also in C++? Does it have a specific name?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini They are called bit fields; it is standard C but very much implementation defined. Historically they have a bad reputation both due to being so unportable and for quality/performance of the code generated. Doing the bitwise arithmetic manually is safer and better defined, but as illustrated here the bitfield solution is more readable.

Comment: (Also note that if you post about bitfields you will certainly get downvotes here.)

Comment: the only downside of the bitfields: they are not portable. Bit order or padding is 100% implementation-defined. I would use the on the uC projects, but not portable ones

Comment: @Michele - About C++. The bit fields are available there too, but like here the specific layout is not portable. The union trick is *formally forbidden* in C++ (you may only read the last member written). But `memcpy` works. And in C++20 we have got a `bit_cast`, specifically for this kind of conversions https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast